# Use an svg as clipping mask for div

Tags: svg, css, html, clipping-mask

I would like to use a svg as a clipping mask for a div, so that where the svg is placed you see the fixed background. I tried to explain it here:

[image]

The size of the svg should depend on the screenwidth.

Is there a possibility to do that?

Comment: I might do it something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/k3p8w16c/

Comment: @Joonas Perfect! That's exactly what I had in mind. Great, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to make a big SVG covering the whole div in Illustrator with a transparency mask:

[image: mask]

Here the result as a fixed image and a background image class to the div:

https://codepen.io/danielillo/pen/XYNvME

Comment: Thanks! But I was looking vor the ability to let it adjust to the screenwidth **while** the yellow foreground still covers 100% of the screen. It seems as if that would need a different approach, if possible after all.